# How can I copy files by creating symlinks?

Tags: unix, symlink

I want to traverse a filesystem and copy parts of it to another filesystem by creating symlinks instead of copying anything.

`rsync` would be ideal if it had something like a `--local-copy-via-symlink` option, because `rsync`'s inclusion/exclusion filters would be the best way to specify what I want to copy.

I know I can do this with a script, but is there a clever command that does this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A symlink is not a copy of a file, the link is a pointer to another file.
2. Changing the data either by using the filename or the link name does not result in a two different files, which would be the case with a real copy.
3. Removing the original doesn't retain (a copy of) the data at the location of the symlink, instead you get what's called a broken symlink, something that points to file location that no longer exists.

Simply put, there is nothing "clever" to do.

---

**EDIT**

Instead of creating symlinks, Linux has the concept of a "bind" mount. Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount part of the file hierarchy some where else. The call is:

```
                 mount --bind olddir newdir
```

or fstab entry is:

```
                 /olddir /newdir none bind
```

After this call the same contents is accessible in two places. This preserves all existing permissions. but you don't have symbolic links either.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know what a symlink is! By "copy" I meant "link," because I don't actually want to make copies. I want to create symlinks.

Comment: Ah semantics! You don'y want to copy files, and you want something more efficient than creating individual symlinks?

Comment: I've done this a slightly different way, but what I really wanted was to run rsync (or something similar with inclusions/exclusions) such that it created symlinks rather than copying files. (My response to your answer was kind of snarky, so I'll give you credit for a correct answer as an apology.)